# How to using url to star another android app?

Tags: android, url, android-intent

Recently, i installed an android app ,i found that when i browse a specific `Url` in my phone browser(app should run in backstage right now) , app will automatically start. i want to know how achieve this ? i tried to use

```
"intent-filter <data schema:"http" android:host="*****" />
```

,but it doesn't work the same as that app (start automatically ).I upload video to youtube about how this program perform, [youtube link](http://youtu.be/NqZL_CaiA3E).
 You can download app here： [baidu_map_download](http://gdown.baidu.com/data/wisegame/83881cf03359ea24/baiduditu_461.apk)

Specific url： http://map.baidu.com/mobile/zt/locshare

Comment: I have edited my answer again, Edit 2 should contain what you are looking for. Please consider up voting and accepting my answer if I helper you.

Comment: You actually have not seen what i have written above:"intent-filter <data schema:"http" android:host="*****" /> . If i add code like this, app will start but not automatic(system let user choose which app to launch,because url can be monitored by many browser). But thanks for your effort.

Comment: It will never start automatically. Default apps cannot be set and most of all should not be set by the app. This always requires a user interaction, at least once. And that is the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: The reason why it works on your phone automatically is because you have set this app as default at some point in the past.

Comment: NO, i have never do this before. but maybe app have do this in their project?

Answer (score 0):

You as in the developer only has a passive influence on that. Basically in your manifest you can set an IntentFilter for your Activities. For example your main Activity should have the Intents android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER.

example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    // Here the Intent Filter is set
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you want your app to be launched by a specific Intent - You can look up any available Intents [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) - than you have to add this Intent to the IntentFilter. The user of the smartphone can then choose the default application for an Intent from all the apps which have this Intent in their IntentFilter

**Edit 1:**

You can show a chooser dialog for a specific Intent, which lets the user pick the default app for this Intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String title = getString(R.string.chooser_title);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

**Edit 2:**

This IntentFilter handles all links to google.com

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="google.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add it to your application tag in your manifest and your app will be launched when you browse url's which fall in that category.

Comment: I already know what you say in the last few words, so i emphasize "automatically start ",not to let user to  choose default application for an intent from all the apps which have this Intent in their Intent-Filter.

Comment: I don't think you can do this automatically. And in any case you should not do it. But you can create a chooser dialog which lets the user pick the default app at any time.

Comment: First，app actually start automatically (may be use third-party api).  Second, i mean " i browse a specific Url in my phone browser, app will automatically start" , so i think should add some code to monitor my  behavior:open the specific URL but not to add intent.

Comment: Well for url's you would add the intent ACTION_VIEW to your activity's IntentFilter. You then can read the Url from the Intent in your Activity and check if it is the Url you need. But the app should not enforce this behavior by trying to automatically make it the default app. This is a usability issue and letting the user choose the default app is part of the standard android behavior. You're not going to get around that nor should you even try.

Comment: As I said, you can do exactly that by adding ACTION_VIEW to the IntentFilter in your manifest. I will edit my question accordingly.